# calling php database connection class

Tags: php, database

```
class Users {

    function __construct(){
        //database configuration
        $dbServer = 'localhost'; //Define database server host
        $dbUsername = 'abc'; //Define database username
        $dbPassword = 'def'; //Define database password
        $dbName = 'ghi'; //Define database name

        //connect databse
        $con = mysqli_connect($dbServer,$dbUsername,$dbPassword,$dbName);
        if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
            die("Failed to connect with MySQL: ".mysqli_connect_error());
        }else{
            $this->connect = $con;
        }
    }
}
```

How can I call a new database connection for a new file using this.This is my function.php. I want to call this now for user.php.

Comment: $somevar = new Users();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in user.php. First include the function.php at very top of the code after:

```
<?php
    include "pathtofunction.php";
```

Where you want to call a new database connection do this:

```
$db=new Users();
```

And you need to create the field connect before to access it.
Like this:After

```
class Users{
    public $connect;
```

Comment: first two parts I understood, last part I couldn't. I am a newbie. It would be great if you write how to call public class connect for the connection

Comment: $connect is not a class. And you were storing the connection status in a field. So you need to declare it first. and thats what i did. you can simply add the line or else you may end of with errors.

Comment: if it has helped you don't forget to mark it as answer.

Comment: so in user.php file will I be using $sql = mysqli_query(this->connect,"UPDATE `users` SET wish='".$wish."', mobile='".$mobile."' WHERE `id` = 5");    or   $sql = mysqli_query(this->connect,"UPDATE `users` SET wish='".$wish."', mobile='".$mobile."' WHERE `id` = 5");

Comment: No you should use the variable that called the class Users(), Use $db->connect.

Comment: kudos to you! you such a help :). Please share contact we can connect apart from here.

Comment: silwalanish@gmail.com is my email. connect with me facebook [http://www.facebook.com/silwalanish](http://www.facebook.com/silwalanish)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my tested answer, first you need to build the Database class as seen below, you need to put it in a PHP file and include it from your homepage (might be the index.php page). Then, you need to initiate an instance of your class from the homepage to connect to the database PHP class which will connect to the MySQL database the built-in function mysql_connect, the code is very well explained in details in this great article:  [www.muwakaba.com/php-database-connection](http://www.muwakaba.com/php-database-connection)

```
<?php
// Class definition
class Database{

    // The constructor function
    public function __construct(){
        // The properties 
        $this->host = "your_DB_host_address";
        $this->login = "your_DB_login_name";
        $this->password = "your_DB_password";
        $this->name = "your_DB_name";

        // The methods 
        $this->connect(); 
        $this->select();
    }

    // The connect function
    private function connect(){
        $this->connection = mysql_connect($this->host, $this->login, $this->password) or die("Sorry! Cannot connect to the database");
    }

    // The select function
    private function select(){
        mysql_select_db($this->name, $this->connection);
    } 

}
?>
```